# How to setup multiple domains in SendGrid?

Tags: sendgrid

We want to send the mails from multiple domains like test@abc.com, test@def.com over the same sendgrid account.
How to setup these multiple domains. I know that we can use the sub user management of the send grid. But how does it work. 
Is adding the dedicated IP in spf records in enough for sender email validation.
How it is different from CNAME records?